# New containers accessing volume on preexisting container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I have a 'master' container, that should be already running when starting all the others.

In it i have a `conf/` directory, that this service is monitoring and applying the relevant changes.

How can i have each new container drop a file in this directory?

---

real scenario:

given my `docker-compose.yml` below, i want each service (`portainer`, `whoami`, `apache`) to drop a `.yml` file in the `"./traefik/conf/:/etc/traefik/conf/"` path mapping of the `traefik` service.

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"

services:

    traefik:
        image: traefik
        env_file: ./traefik/env
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - ./traefik/conf/:/etc/traefik/conf/
            - ./traefik/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml

    portainer:
        image: portainer/portainer
        depends_on: [traefik]
        command: --no-auth -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

    whoami:
        image: containous/whoami
        depends_on: [traefik]
```

### portainer.traefik.yml

```
http:
    routers:
        portainer:
            entryPoints: [http]
            middlewares: [redirect-to-http]
            service: portainer-preauth@docker
            rule: Host(`portainer.docker.mydomain`)
```

### whoami.traefik.yml

```
http:
    routers:
        whoami:
            entryPoints: [http]
            middlewares: [redirect-to-http]
            service: whoami-preauth@docker
            rule: Host(`whoami.docker.mydomain`)
```

---

> Where are the files portainer.traefik.yml and whoami.traefik.yml
>   located? If they are on host machine, you can directly copy them to
>   ./traefik/conf/. – Shashank V

the thing is i cant have all files in `traefik/conf`.
this would require manually dropping a file there every time i create a new image.
i believe that every service should be responsible for its own files.
also, when `traefik` starts and finds files of those other services that haven't started yet, it logs lots of errors.
to avoid this behavior, i would like to put the file there only when the container is started.

below is is the project file structure.

[image: project file structure]

Comment: Where are the files `portainer.traefik.yml` and `whoami.traefik.yml` located? If they are on host machine, you can directly copy them to ./traefik/conf/.

Comment: @ShashankV updated the question with the file structure. the thing is i dont want to have all files in traefik/conf. every service should be responsible for its files. also, when traefik starts and finds files of thoses other services that havent started yet, it logs lots of errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a volume across all services. Just define it in your docker-compose.yml and assign it to each service:

```
version: "3.5"

services:

    traefik:
        image: traefik
        env_file: ./traefik/env
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - ./traefik/conf/:/etc/traefik/conf/
            - ./traefik/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
            - foo:/path/to/share/

    portainer:
        image: portainer/portainer
        depends_on: [traefik]
        command: --no-auth -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - foo:/another/path/to/share/

    whoami:
        image: containous/whoami
        depends_on: [traefik]
        volumes:
          - foo:/and/another/path/

    volumes:
      foo:
        driver: local
```

This is the equivalent to the [--volumes-from](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volumes-from-container---volumes-from) feature of "plain" Docker. Or at least, what comes closest to it.

Your master container would then have to use the same volume. If this container doesn't run within the same Docker Compose context, you have to define this volume externally before.

Comment: i was thinking about mapping the file to the host filesystem instead of `ADD` in the `Dockerfile`. is that possible? im really trying to avoid making constant changes do `Dockerfile` and rebuilding.

Comment: Mapping a file to the host filesystem is exactly what you do with a volume. :) When using volumes, you wouldn't have to change your Dockerfile. [Check this out](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for a good explanation about volumes and how to use them.